# Could not load file c#

Tags: c#, powershell, error-handling

In my pc(win10) it's working perfectly, but if I try to run in my workplace pc(win7) I get this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7mX5.jpg
My button code is this:

```
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        PowerShellInstance.AddScript("cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like \"*Target:*\"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace \" \",\"\" -replace \"Target:\",\"\")}}");
        PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
        OutlookMsg om = new OutlookMsg
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
        };
        om.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

If I clcik the details the exceptions show this, how can I fix this?

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Helpdesk.Form1.OutlookBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
```

I deleted this part It was only path to dll

```
************** JIT Debugging ********

******
    To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
    application or computer (machine.config) must have the
    jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
    The application must also be compiled with debugging
    enabled.

    For example:

    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

    When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
    will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
    rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Is this .net core or .net framework?

Comment: It's .net framework

Comment: Is the correct version of the .Net framework installed on your work computer? When you copied the program over did you make sure to copy all the files?

Comment: I clicked publish and it created setup exe and tried to run in my work computer and I got this:Cannot download the application. The application is missing required files. Contact application vendor for assistance. And I used to the exe what is in the debug.How can I fix this?(This error only show in win7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer does not have the assembly. It seems you just need to install the runtime library

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Install this one  `Windows6.1-KB2506143-***.msu` for Windows 7